# Next js does not load dynamic page in build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a next js app that uses dynamic routes.
The dynamic routes work perfectly on dev mode but when I build it and ship it to netlify they throw a 404
[image]
here is my code :
in __app.js

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { initGA, logPageView } from 'analytics';
import 'rc-drawer/assets/index.css';
import 'rc-tabs/assets/index.css';
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { MantineProvider } from '@mantine/core';
import { NotificationsProvider } from '@mantine/notifications';


export default function CustomApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter()
  useEffect(() => {
    initGA();
    logPageView();
    Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', logPageView);
  }, []);

  if(router == '/') {return <Component {...pageProps} />;}
  else {return  <MantineProvider withGlobalStyles withNormalizeCSS> <NotificationsProvider> <Component {...pageProps} /></NotificationsProvider></MantineProvider> }
}
```

and here is my  next config:

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const optimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');

const nextConfiguration = {
  target: 'serverless', //will output independent pages that don't require a monolithic server. It's only compatible with next start or Serverless deployment platforms (like ZEIT Now) — you cannot use the custom server API.
};

module.exports = withPlugins([optimizedImages], nextConfiguration);
```

What I need is for the [calendar].jsx to be able to run when accessed

Comment: does this happen when you build it locally? and do you see any console errors when you access that dynamic page?

Comment: so, /p/pricing is GOOD, but /foo is bad?

Comment: yes @jamesemanon

Comment: Have you tried using  **Catch all routes** : `[...calendar].jsx` ?

Comment: paste the build output and `[calendar].tsx` file. Maybe you are missing `getStaticPros` or something like that? Also have you tried to test it on Vercel just to rule out config issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue doesn't seem to be related to the folder structure.

However there is a high chance it is related to `target: 'serverless'` in your next config, since [netfly docs -> suggested configuration values](https://docs.netlify.com/integrations/frameworks/next-js/overview/#suggested-configuration-values) mention that:

> serverless target deprecated
>
> The serverless and experimental-serverless-trace targets are
> deprecated in Next 12, and all builds with Next.js Runtime use the
> default server target. If you previously set the target in your
> next.config.js, you should remove it.

(so you should remove `target: 'serverless'` from your next config)

You can also check [this answer](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/20790#issuecomment-755178273) and [this answer](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/20487#issuecomment-753884085) for more information about why `serverless` is not recommended in general (except for very specific cases).

Comment: Hi @Berci , i completely deleted the target ..... same stuff, you can check it at https://calendris.netlify.app/hola ```const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const optimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');


module.exports = withPlugins([optimizedImages]);
```

Comment: It seems it is a netlify problem, i changed the hosting and now it works